# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow How to create a step that changes a field to be required

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a Workflow for a list in SharePoint 2010. The workflow has multiple steps. I have a field (person or group) that needs to be required in step 6 (the person in step 6 should select the person in the field, but sometimes forgets to do so). In step 9 the person selected will get an email and need to fill out a portion of the infopath form. The person responsible for steps 1-5 do not know who to enter in that field so i can't make it a mandatory field in the beginning. When the person in step 6 forgets to select someone, step 9 gets held up because no one gets the email.

Answer (score 0):

If SharePoint Designer is your only option then you should split the workflow into two different workflows. Keep steps 1-5 in the first workflow and put the remaining steps in a new workflow. In the new workflow, create an initiation form to collect the information you need. Initiation forms in SharePoint Designer support "Person or Group" types and you can make the field required.

Other possible solutions would be outside of SharePoint Designer, including a workflow created in Visual Studio or a JavaScript solution.